# Tomato soup without a blender?

Tags: tomatoes

Can you use canned tomato puree to make a simple tomato soup? I want to make my own tomato soup but all the recipes I find call for a blender to puree the soup, and I don't have one! So I was wondering if canned tomato puree and chicken broth will do the trick.

Comment: If you are going to buy cans then why not just buy canned soup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use pureed ingredients, or puree afterward...it makes little difference.  With no blender, in a pinch you can push your product through a sieve.

Comment: Personally I prefer the texture of soup pushed through a sieve and I do this with tomato soup and with pumpkin soup (my favourite).

Answer (score 0):

A tomato soup made of fresh tomatoes is really the best. What causes trouble here is the skin and the middle part of the tomatoes, the rest of them becomes puree in the course of cooking. Boil water and immerse the whole tomatos for 1 min. Then you can remove their thin skin an effortless way. Cut out their green stalks and throw them including their juice into the soup pot. You can add some cans of chopped ones if you need large quantity, but having at least half from fresh tomatos makes a difference. Otherwise I used to start with frying some finely chopped onions and celery, adding a bit of chili and tandoori masala for last 2 mins of frying, then the tomatos and water as needed. Later add finely chopped garlic and some pepper, and maybe basil. Also sweet potatoes, aubergine and parsley can make the tomato soup better, but then you really need a blender or go for a chunky soup.

Comment: This does not answer the question